# AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled despite installing pytorch w/cuda and all libraries showing up in conda env list

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I recently updated my OS (ubuntu). This seemed to break the pytorch installation in all my conda environments. Trying to run pytorch code with cuda in any of these environments , or newly created environments with torch installed
` yields:

```
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

I tried to clear all the environments, and make a new environment.
I install pytorch using:
`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Upon checking the installed packages with `conda list`, it seems all of the necessary packages are there (irrelevant packages omitted for brevity):

```
pytorch                   2.0.1           cpu_py311h53e38e9_0  
pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
pytorch-lightning         2.0.3           py311h06a4308_0  
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
torchaudio                2.0.2               py311_cu118    pytorch
torchmetrics              0.11.4          py311h92b7b1e_1  
torchvision               0.15.2              py311_cu118    pytorch
torchaudio                2.0.2               py311_cu118    pytorch
torchvision               0.15.2              py311_cu118    pytorch
cuda-cudart               11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                11.8.87                       0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 11.8.86                       0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cudatoolkit               11.8.0               h6a678d5_0
```

There do not seem to be any conflicts. `nvidia-smi` works. `nvcc --version` works.

I have tried:

- Deleting all environments and setting them up again
- Rebooting
- Updating & upgrading packages
- Installing using pip
- Installing pytorch in the base environment

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this googling in the future:
For some reason anaconda automatically installed the cpu version of pytorch. I reinstalled Anaconda completely and that did the trick.